# print the double of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the double of a number.

If I input `5`, why does this print `55`:

```
number = input("Input number \n")

double = number * 2

print(double)
```

and why does this print `10`, as expected:

```
number = int(input("Input number \n"))

double = number * 2

print(double)
```

Comment: 1) Thanks. Please share how you would do it. 2) I used " for this example. I will not use it when asking. thanks again!

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug, it works for me and prints 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a difference between python2's `input()` and python3's `input()` function.

In python2 we had 2 functions, `raw_input()` for reading input as a string and `input()` for numeric input.

In python 3 there is no `raw_input()` but only one method which is `input()` that by default read as a string.

so if you are trying to input some number you have to typecast it.

`num = int(input("Input number \n"))`

if you want to evaluate a expression of numbers you can use `eval`

```
>>> a = eval(input("Input Number: "))
2+3+4
>>> a
9
```

Do not use eval on production though!

Comment: Do not use eval this is terrible advice

Comment: there are a multitude of questions and answers on SO related to why using eval when taking input is not  a good idea

Answer (score 2):

In the second case you convert the input to an *integer*, which can be multiplied by two to get the expected result. In the first case, you multiply a *string* (instead of an integer) by two, which results in the string twice, hence '55'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought Python detects the type of the variable by it's input. I didn't realise it saw it as a string. Thanks again!

Comment: @BogdanNedelcu There are more types in Python than are dreamed of by your philosophy.